# SQL ReadPast Has No Effect

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

In order to accommodate concurrency for a given table that will be under constant fire of both updates and selects I'm trying to introduce an efficient locking pattern on an Azure SQL DB. After investigating READPAST for selects and WITH (ROWLOCK) for updates I'm not seeing the results I would expect nor others are reporting. My select statement with READPAST always returns rows that are in the process of being updated. Consider my simple scenario:

Table [Job] :
Id varchar(12) PK | CreatedOn datetime | StatusId smallint

I seed the Job table with 5 records and set the StatusId to 0 for all.

In one session I execute the following command **without committing**:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE JOB WITH (ROWLOCK) SET StatusId = 1
```

In another session I execute the following command

```
SELECT * FROM Job WITH (READPAST)
```

The select statement executes and returns all 5 rows with their **pre-updated** StatusId (0). It's my understanding that READPAST is supposed to skip the rows which are locked. I have verified the lock is indeed present and granted using the sp_WhoIsActive proc.

What I am missing to get this scenario working correctly?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Typically you use READPAST in combination with UPDLOCK and transactions to implement a competing-consumer pattern for distributing work.  What is your intention in using READPAST here?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you assume locking isn't efficient? (It is) SQL Server already allows concurrent access. ROWLOCK is the default unless you try to modify a large number of pages in which cases it's cheaper to lock more data than maintain a lot of locks. Are you trying to perform a bulk update while others are reading?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a simple queue where Jobs could have a status of (at it's simplest) Queued, InProgress and Completed.  Process A should be a to select N number of Jobs while also updating those rows to InProgress.  Process B should be able to do the same but will skip over any rows that are currently locked.

Comment: A common solution to the Queue problem is `UPDATE...OUTPUT inserted.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SQL Database has the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option on by default. That uses row-versioning instead of locking for read consistency in the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level so the `SELECT` query will return the pre-update row version until the `UPDATE` transaction is committed.

You can override the isolation level in the SELECT query with a hint like below:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.job WITH(REPEATABLEREAD, READPAST);
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of the WHY but aside from re-creating the DB without READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT can you suggest an option to query the DB as is with the desired result?

Comment: @Mike, I added one method to my answer. There may be better ways to implement queues in SQL Server but much depends on your use case.

Comment: This appears to work given the generalized details I've provided. I'll investigate further solutions regarding Queue implementations but for now I have something with work with. Thanks.

Comment: `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` is another option for switching off row-versioning.